# A RoR v3 routing question?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I was wondering if it is possible to route to something like this `/:user_id` `user_id` is a custom id that doesn't just use integers it uses other characters like so `NM-001`. Then in my controller I have `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`. Then in view `<%= @user.name %>`

Comment: Yes that is possible. Is this `user_id` string the primary key in your table or not? If it's not your primary key, you have to use `find_by_user_id` instead of `find`. If it is you primary key, you have to tell your `User` model that the primary key is `user_id` instead of `id`.

Comment: @mischa `user_id` is not my primary key. So I will now go try out what you said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can have such a route. However, if your `:user_id` will contain periods then you'll want to include

```
:constraints => { :user_id => /.*/ }
```

in the route options to keep Rails from trying to interpret the `.whatever` part of the `:user_id` as a format specifier.

Then, you'll get `params[:user_id]` in your controller and you can turn that into an object however you want. You'd probably want to do what [mischa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84631/mischa) said in the comments:

```
@user = User.find_by_user_id(params[:user_id])
```

Also, if you really want to use `/:user_id` as your route, you'll want to make sure that none of your userids match any of your present or future top-level routes.

Comment: When I try this in my controller `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` then in my view `<%= @user.name %>` my routes `resources :users` `match '/:user_id', :to => 'users#show'` it returns the error `Couldn't find User without an ID`

Comment: @Leozar100: Your controller should be using `find_by_user_id` as mischa noted in yesterday's comments.

Comment: Oh now I see `find_by_user_id` method uses the `params[:user_id]` as an arguement. Thx